# Group by LIKE of a column value

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a hypothetical query such as this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM subscriptions
GROUP by plan_type
```

And a table similar to the one below:

```
+----+-----------------------+-------------+--+
| id |       plan_type       | customer_id |  |
+----+-----------------------+-------------+--+
|  1 | gold_2017             |         523 |  |
|  2 | gold_2016_recurring   |        2300 |  |
|  3 | silver_2016           |         234 |  |
|  4 | silver_2017_recurring |        2593 |  |
|  5 | platinum_recurring    |        4123 |  |
+----+-----------------------+-------------+--+
```

Desired result:

```
+-------+----------+
| count |   type   |
+-------+----------+
|     2 | gold     |
|     2 | silver   |
|     1 | platinum |
+-------+----------+
```

Is there any way to group these entries using a GROUP BY and a LIKE statement (LIKE "silver", LIKE "gold", LIKE "platinum", etc)?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Post what would be the desired result

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @lamak Updated at bottom

Comment: Then use @GordonLinoff's answer, it does exactly this

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `case`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN plan_type LIKE 'silver%' THEN 'silver'
             WHEN plan_type LIKE 'gold%' THEN 'gold'
             WHEN plan_type LIKE 'platinum%' THEN 'platinum'
        END) as plan_grp, COUNT(*)
FROM subscriptions
GROUP by (CASE WHEN plan_type LIKE 'silver%' THEN 'silver'
               WHEN plan_type LIKE 'gold%' THEN 'gold'
               WHEN plan_type LIKE 'platinum%' THEN 'platinum'
          END);
```

Some databases allow you to use a column alias in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Exactly what the OP was looking for, +1

Comment: Hmm question -- why is it necessary to use LIKE statements in the SELECT part of the query? Would the LIKE statements in the GROUP BY not be sufficient?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Good answer +1... Answer would be even better if you include the `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, plan_type ASC`  then the query should give the desired result:

Answer (score 3):

You can group on some string function to reduce your plan type to the substring you want.

Sql Server example:

```
SELECT 
    left(plan_type,charindex('_',plan_type)-1) as plan_type
  , COUNT(*)
FROM subscriptions
GROUP by left(plan_type,charindex('_',plan_type)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding like clause should work as below query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count,
(CASE WHEN plan_type LIKE 'silver%' THEN 'silver'
             WHEN plan_type LIKE 'gold%' THEN 'gold'
             WHEN plan_type LIKE 'platinum%' THEN 'platinum'
        END) AS type
FROM subscriptions
GROUP by (CASE WHEN plan_type LIKE 'silver%' THEN 'silver'
           WHEN plan_type LIKE 'gold%' THEN 'gold'
           WHEN plan_type LIKE 'platinum%' THEN 'platinum' END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(plan_type, '_', 1) FROM subscriptions
Group By SUBSTRING_INDEX(Remotehost, '_', 1)
```